# ember parse adapter hasMany error

Tags: ember.js, parse-platform, ember-data

In the database on the parse.com I have a table `Item` with the following fields:

```
"objectId": "O0NkhZAcMd",
"price": "100",
"topping": [
    {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Topping",
        "objectId": "iKbMWHZrEB"
    },
    {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Topping",
        "objectId": "yIIkePYKSS"
    },
    {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Topping",
        "objectId": "lZJ4Kpqodf"
    },
...
]
```

Topping has a field `title` and `price`.
For this database I have the following models:

**app/models/item.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  objectId: DS.attr(),
  price: DS.attr(),
  topping: DS.hasMany('topping', {async: true}),
});
```

**app/models/topping.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  objectId: DS.attr(),
  price: DS.attr(),
  title: DS.attr(),
});
```

When I added `topping: DS.hasMany('topping', {async: true})` in `app/models/item.js` I started getting the following error:

```
Error while processing route: menu Assertion Failed: Ember Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the `topping` relationship instead it found an object. If this is a polymorphic relationship please specify a `type` key. If this is an embedded relationship please include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and specify the `topping` property in your serializer's attrs object.
```

I do not know what type I need to specify and where to do it.
May be anybody can help me?

I use:

- ember 1.13.7
- ember-data 1.13.8
- ember-parse-adapter 0.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `belongs_to` relationship to your `topping` model.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  objectId: DS.attr(),
  price:    DS.attr(),
  title:    DS.attr(),
  item:     DS.belongsTo('item', { async: true }) 
});
```